# When I use CnosDB, I find that drop VNode causes write failure

Tags: database, cnosdb

cnosdb version: ea47f4eb81cee966648f95d4ad34044e8a6f28d3
clusters: 2 data,3 meta

The first time to write data succeeded, but after dropping the VNode, the second time to write data failed, and the VNode was not created

The first data write was successful:

```
curl -XPOST -u "root:" "http://127.0.0.1:8902/api/v1/write?db=public" -d "ma,ta=a fa=1"
select * from ma;
+----------------------------+----+-----+
| time | ta | fa |
+----------------------------+----+-----+
| 2023-04-27T10:14:25.373394 | a | 1.0 |
+----------------------------+----+-----+
```

Find and drop the unique VNode :

```
DROP VNODE 6;
select * from ma;
Query took 0.021 seconds.
```

The second attempt to write data failed, and VNode not be created:

```
curl -XPOST -u "root:" "http://127.0.0.1:8902/api/v1/write?db=public" -d "ma,ta=a fa=1"
select * from ma;
Query took 0.020 seconds.
```

Writing to another node 8912 also failed, and VNode not be created:

```
curl -XPOST -u "root:" "http://127.0.0.1:8912/api/v1/write?db=public" -d "ma,ta=a fa=1"
8902/8912
select * from ma;
Query took 0.020 seconds.
```

In my opinion, whether CnosDB VNode is deleted or not, the written data should not be affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, I found this issue of cnosdb when browsing github, which may be related to the problem I raised. If this [issue](https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/issues/1192) is updated, this issue may be solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).